# Quick question about $\mathbb{C}$ considered as field extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

In algebra, one way to understand $\mathbb{C}$ is to consider it as a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$.

What (sometimes) worries me is this: From this point of view, does $\mathbb{C}$ really contain a genuine copy of $\mathbb{R}$? I hope my question makes sense. To me, it is quite obvious that $\mathbb{C}$ contains some field, say $\mathcal{R}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. But what we really want is that $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{R}$ itself?

**Update:** As far as "algebra" concerns, as long as we are only working with the binary operations $\times$ and $+$, it might be pointless trying to distinguishing the true $\mathbb{R}$ and the isomorphic copy due to isomorphism. However, when we do more complicated things (taking limit, taking integral, considering topological structure, etc.), I assume it would be natural to question whether the same conclusions carries over?

Comment: From this point of view, $K$ isn't really $\Bbb C$, so ... :)

Comment: @pjs36 OK... Probably it's not a very well-written question... I am simply confused because I just suddenly don't know how I should understand $\mathbb{C}$......

Comment: I think it it's perfectly well-written! My point was, depending on your view of "what $\Bbb C$ is"/how it's defined, $K$ is *merely* isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ (just like there are subfields of $K$ that are *merely* isomorphic to $\Bbb R$) -- so the identity crisis, if there is one, goes both ways.

Comment: Obviously "above my pay grade" but wouldn't $\mathbb{C}$ contain $\mathbb{R}$ via $\forall c \in \mathbb{C}: \Im(c) = 0 \rightarrow c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In some way, his question reduces to : is $\mathbb{C}$ the completion of $\mathbb{Q} (i) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2+1)$ or is it $\mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2+1)$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ ? I think it deserves a discussion on why $x^2+1$ is special : for instance the completion of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2-1)$ is the same as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I can't really conceive why the field in C wouldn't be th "real" R.  In fact, I don't see how a field *can't* be a subfield of its extensions.  I feel much more confident that R is the "real"  subfield of C than the Q is the "real" subset R.  So I understand your question, but I don't understand your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is going to turn out to be very difficult to answer to your satisfaction - what, after all, *is* $\mathbb{R}$?

What do I mean? Well, let's say we all agree what the rationals are. Then is a real number

- An equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rationals?
- A set of Dedekind cuts in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Note that these are fundamentally different set-theoretic objects: the former is a set of sequences of rationals, while the second is just a set of rationals. And these aren't the only ways to think of $\mathbb{R}$.

So any time you ask a question of the form "Is $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of [thing]?", you have to first specify what exactly you mean by $\mathbb{R}$. And nobody does that . . .

. . . Because what we're *really* interested in is fields *up to isomorphism*.

---

EDIT: This is what I get for writing an answer on a plane! :P

I think my last line - above the edit - may come off as dismissive. **It shouldn't**. When I write that "what we're really interested in is fields up to isomorphism," I do **not** mean that questions that dig deeper than isomorphism are non-mathematical. Rather, I mean that when we speak of "the reals" in mathematical practice, this is the viewpoint we're (almost always) tacitly adopting.

What sort of question is "what are the reals *exactly*?" (Or the rationals. Or the integers.) Well, there's certainly a philosophical aspect, but I'd argue that that doesn't render it non-mathematical. But it does mean we have to be satisfied with answers that are really more about set theory than they are about algebra.

More fundamentally, the real problem is in determining what criteria we use to judge the possible answers. If I give you two definitions of $\mathbb{R}$, how do you tell which one is "more true" (let alone how do we identify one as being *exactly right*)?

Indeed, one extremely reasonable response is to reject phrases like "the reals" as meaningless - we can talk about complete ordered Archimedean fields, but singling one of them out to be the "right" reals would be bizarre (so the argument goes). In fact, we can view this line of thought as an indictment of set-theoretic foundations in general (look up "structural set theory"). My own philosophical opinions are poorly formed and frequently changing (to make up for the poorly-formedness), but this is a viewpoint I have a lot of sympathy for.

Comment: Speaking of "agree[ing] about what the rationals are," a quick question: I know that a rigorous definition of the rationals can be a bit cumbersome, in some sense: equivalence classes of pairs of integers (who themselves, gasp, may be considered equivalence classes of natural numbers!). Are there any legitimately competing definitions for the rationals, as in the case of Dedekind cuts/Cauchy sequences for the reals?

Comment: Pardon me but is my question really, still a mathematics question?

Comment: In modern mathematics we go one step further: we simply don't care what something is, but rather what can we do with it. That is the axiomatic approach that completely frees us from pointless discussions that plagued the minds of many people - but no more.

Comment: @pjs36 there about 20 constructions of the reals. There far fewer of the rationals. The thing is that the rationals are really very very simple, especially when compared to the reals. The reals really are super complicated. Both to define and to study. Much of modern mathematics comes from trying to answer simple questions about the reals.

Comment: @Misakov your question is a mathematical one, and one that you should resolve in the form of "now I understand that the question is in modern terms simply meaningless". When you truly understand that, you will have learned something important.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Ummm... I see, I guess I will take it for granted for a while. You see, that's the part of algebra that confuses me. I really like analysis and in analysis we (or maybe I) spend quite some time understanding and playing with definitions, but in algebra seems like everything is "up to isomorphism"

Comment: @Misakov That's still present in analysis, though - what exactly is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Misakov It is only a mirage. The same underlying principle applies. What is certainly true is that in analysis the study of just one system, namely the reals, can keep you occupied for a life-time. So it may appear that you study just a select few structures, but the up-to-iso is still there. But the up-to-iso is also a smokescreen. It is really the axioms we care about. Nobody should care about what something is - only about what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You really mean $K=\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ so the elements of $K$ are of the form $a+bx$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$.  As you say, $K$ has a subfield, the elements with $b=0$, that is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.  What is the difference between a subfield of $K$ that is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, a genuine copy of $\Bbb R$, and $\Bbb R$ itself?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter. As a philosophical point, it's best not to worry about whether two structures are "actually the same" rather than isomorphic in a canonical way.